# interchanging and manipulating two form input values

Tags: javascript, forms, ecmascript-6

I've created a calculator that requires a value in either months or years in order to perform a calculation. The calculator works with one exception: It is required that the two input fields update based on the value of each other. here's an example of the behavior I am attempting to recreate:

https://www.bankrate.com/calculators/mortgages/loan-calculator.aspx

I apologize in advance if the following example reads poorly, but here it goes:

If a user enters 72 'months', the 'years' input will divide months by 12 and display the result. After doing a little tooling around, I found that using [a, b] = [b*12, a/12] gets me halfway there. The problem I'm running into is that once values have been entered, the value of the most recently updated input is updated with the previous value (including the calculation). For example, User enters 60 months > years is populated with the value of 5 > user changes months to a value of 72 > years is populated with a value of 6 > months is automatically populated with a value of 60 (years remains at a value of 6)

Here's the JS:

```
const loan = () => {
    let principal = document.getElementById('principal')
    let interestRate = document.getElementById('interestRate')
    let terms = document.getElementById('terms')
    let termsInYears = document.getElementById('termsInYears')
    let payment = document.getElementById('payment')
    let total = document.getElementById('total')
    let totalInterest = document.getElementById('totalInterest')
    let closingCosts = document.getElementById('closingCosts')
    let netAfterFees = document.getElementById('netAfterFees')
    let totalFeesAndInterest = document.getElementById('totalFeesAndInterest')
    let trueCost = document.getElementById('trueCost')

    let amount = parseFloat(principal.value)
    let interest = parseFloat(interestRate.value) / 100 / 12
    let payments = parseFloat(terms.value)
    let fees = parseFloat(closingCosts.value)

    if(!fees) {
        closingCosts.value = 0
    }

    [terms.value, termsInYears.value] = [termsInYears.value*12, terms.value/12]


    let x = Math.pow(1 + interest, payments)
    let monthly = (amount * x * interest) / (x-1)
    let totalPay = (monthly * payments)

    if (isFinite(monthly) && payment) {
        payment.innerHTML = monthly.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,')
        netAfterFees.innerHTML = (amount - fees).toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,')
        total.innerHTML = (totalPay).toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,')
        totalInterest.innerHTML = ((monthly * payments) - amount).toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,')
        totalFeesAndInterest.innerHTML = (totalPay - amount + fees).toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,')
        trueCost.innerHTML = (((totalPay - amount + fees) / amount)*100).toFixed(2)
    } else {
        payment.innerHTML = '0'
        netAfterFees.innerHTML = '0'
        total.innerHTML = '0'
        totalInterest.innerHTML = '0'
        totalFeesAndInterest.innerHTML = '0'
        trueCost.innerHTML = '0'
    }
}
```

I can't speak on the quality of the working calculator given my experience level. However, it does work. I'm just having one heck of a time getting past this [likely silly] input exchange.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: To fix this, you'll have to determine what has triggered the `loan` function (a change of the `#terms`'s or a change of the `#termsInYears`'s value)

Comment: Thanks Titus. My goal is to trigger on both. So the user may choose to only enter in either field at any given time. Perhaps you're suggesting I add some additional conditional logic here?

Comment: Yes, you will have to change the value only to the input that wan't changed by the user (an additional condition).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this issue using querySelector and then adding an event listener for each input:

```
    document.querySelector('#terms').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
        termsInYears.value = e.target.value / 12
    })

    document.querySelector('#termsInYears').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
        terms.value = e.target.value * 12
    })
```